# How does the gmail apps notify once feature work?

Tags: gmail

I have been looking into the settings to make gmail better for myself however one thing I couldn't get my head around is the notify once option.

If I receive an email I get notified, if I get another one from the same sender and the notify once option is ticked I no longer get another notification. Or does the notify once feature mean from any other sender?

So I've already been notified and I receive another email from a completely different sender, do I then get notified with the notify once option ticked?